# Choosing the best move in the given position

Tags: strategy, tactics, middlegame, planning

I was just guessing the best move in the position.(white to move).

I thought Rc1 would be the best move forcing white to exchange the white's dark square bishop and preserving the white's light squared bishop to neutralize the black's light squared bishop . But the engine gives Bxc2 which doesn't makes as sense as the former.I want to know the idea behind engine's move.

```
[FEN "r3kb1r/pp1q1pp1/2p1p3/3nPb2/3P1N1p/PBN1BQ1P/1Pn2PP1/R2R2K1 w - - 1 1"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 1. Rac1, Black has the intermediate move 1...Nxc3, attacking the rook on d1, which forces White to play 2. bxc3, and then the pawn on a3 is hanging. So Black would likely go 2...Nxe3 followed by 3...Bxa3.

```
[FEN "r3kb1r/pp1q1pp1/2p1p3/3nPb2/3P1N1p/PBN1BQ1P/1Pn2PP1/R2R2K1 w - - 1 1"]

1. Rac1 Nxc3 2. bxc3 Nxe3 3. null Bxa3
```

Comment: This is probably right. Tactics are hidden in almost every position, and engines are far better at finding them than humans are. Therefore computers sometimes give lines that seem a bit unintuitive at first, as they see the underlying tactics in a position much faster than a human could hope to do.

Answer (score 1):

Rac1 for the following reasons:

1) Bxc2 leaves you with a really good Black bishop vs really bad White bishop.

2) Rac1 has an Xray defense of the Knight on c3, so tactics like Nxa3 (removal of the guard) never come up.

3) Ra2 is soooooo passive.

4) Cute tactics like Nfxd5 never work because black can simply recapture with exd5 (Black shouldn't get jumpy and grab the White Rook due to stuff like Nb5 or something IDK.)

Just a few ideas for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

First look at the position of black's king -- it's still in the middle of the board; most of the time this leaves opportunity for an attack or, at the very least, the initiative. White's attacking area would be on the queen side, so black should not go there with the King and the kingside is weakened due to the pawn being on h4. Also black is underdeveloped due to lack of castling, so the rooks are having a hard time communicating. This gives you the forcing sequence to take advantage of these temporary advantages starting with Bxc2. It should follow something like 1...Bxc2; 2. Rdc1 and wherever the bishop moves you could try something like 3. Ncxd5 and once he takes back with either pawn push 4. b4. Now you are restricting his dark square bishop and preparing to open up a front on the queen side of the board. This should be to white's advantage

```
[FEN "r3kb1r/pp1q1pp1/2p1p3/3nPb2/3P1N1p/PBN1BQ1P/1Pn2PP1/R2R2K1 w - - 1 1"]

1. Bxc2 Bxc2 2. Rdc1 null 3. Ncxd5 null 4. b4
```